# table partioning - keep base and partition childs?

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning

I have a table structure I want to partition by timestamp, in ranges of day.

It consists of two tables which has common fields, to make it simple I will use an example of tables A,B as follows:

```
create table A (
    id serial not null, 
    ts timestamp without time zone not null,
    name text,
    some_custom_A_field_1 numeric,
    some_custom_A_field_2 numeric
);

create table B (
    id serial not null, 
    ts timestamp without time zone not null,
    name text,
    some_custom_B_field_1 numeric,
    some_custom_B_field_2 numeric,
    some_custom_B_field_3 numeric,
    some_custom_B_field_4 numeric
);
```

So I have two options, and I'm not sure which one is preferred.

Option #1 - create base table, inherit, partition childs:

```
create table Base (
    id serial not null, 
    ts timestamp without time zone not null,
    name text
)

create table ABase (
    some_custom_A_field_1 numeric,
    some_custom_A_field_2 numeric
)INHERITS (Base );

create table BBase (
    some_custom_B_field_1 numeric,
    some_custom_B_field_2 numeric,
    some_custom_B_field_3 numeric,
    some_custom_B_field_4 numeric
)INHERITS (Base );

CREATE TABLE a_2018_06_24 (CHECK (ts >= '2018-06-24 00:00:00' AND ts < '2018-06-25 00:00:00')) INHERITS (ABase);
CREATE TABLE b_2018_06_24 (CHECK (ts >= '2018-06-24 00:00:00' AND ts < '2018-06-25 00:00:00')) INHERITS (BBase);
```

Option #2 - two base tables partitioned:

```
create table ABase (
    id serial not null, 
    ts timestamp without time zone not null,
    name text,
    some_custom_A_field_1 numeric,
    some_custom_A_field_2 numeric
);

create table BBase (
    id serial not null, 
    ts timestamp without time zone not null,
    name text,
    some_custom_B_field_1 numeric,
    some_custom_B_field_2 numeric,
    some_custom_B_field_3 numeric,
    some_custom_B_field_4 numeric
);

CREATE TABLE a_2018_06_24 (CHECK (ts >= '2018-06-24 00:00:00' AND ts < '2018-06-25 00:00:00')) INHERITS (ABase);
CREATE TABLE b_2018_06_24 (CHECK (ts >= '2018-06-24 00:00:00' AND ts < '2018-06-25 00:00:00')) INHERITS (BBase);
```

Additional info:

1. I'm using version 9.6
2. Table A approx 2M records per day , Table B approx 120M records per day.
3. Use cases - ingest data to tables once a day, run select queries (based on time-series).

What will be the better practice, pros / cons?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name did not know about it, is there more to it then just nicer syntax? as I see I still need to set the partitions / inheritance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just noticed it's only on version 10, I'm using 9.6

Comment: If we ignore the partitioning for a second, do you have a specific use case that led you to consider the `Base` -> `BaseA` / `BaseB` inheritance?

Comment: @IMSoP sometimes I need to cross the <ts,name> combo by timestamp from both tables. E.g. check all events in timeseries for a given name from both A and B